# Import from XML drops leading 0

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, etl, derived-column

I have an SSIS package that imports an XML file into SQL. The data of one particular field could be '112' or '039', for example. It is always three characters and gets padded with a leading 0 if only two.

The Destination field in SQL is varchar. For some or other reason SSIS is changing it to DT_UI2 and in the case of '039', only '39' comes.

I have added a data conversion that converts it to DT_WSTR but this does not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XSD that was originally generated defined this field as unsigned short. Changing it to string and redoing the flow solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Use a derived column with the following expression:

```
RIGHT("000" + (DT_WSTR,50)[Source Column],3)
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that. I ended up editing the XSD file and changed it from unsignedshort to string. That worked

Comment: @opperman.eric then write it as answer, also you can use the derived column as a workaround if needed. Good luck